# Netlogo - move shapes slow

Tags: netlogo, shapes

I need the turtles to move slow.
Currently I tried - it is too fast:

```
to move
ask turtles [
      rt random 90
      lt random 90
      fd 1
]
end
```

I tried to make it slow:

```
to move
every 0.05[
    ask turtles [
          rt random 90
          lt random 90
          fd 1
    ]
]
    end
```

The turtles speed now is ok, but I am not sure that this is a correct approach
What do you think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches. If your problem is that you want them to move slowly compared to the rest of the simulation (so other things in the model continue at their normal speed), then it is best to just move the turtles with smaller steps (so forward a smaller amount).

```
to move
  ask turtles
  [ rt random 90
    lt random 90
    fd 0.05
  ]
end
```

Alternatively, if the problem is visual only - so you want to be able to see things move but still move the same amount every tick - then you can simply slow down the running of the simulation. In the middle of the interface there is a speed slider.

Comment: in the model settings, you can also set the target frame rate to a lower setting, to make it slower without the user having to move the speed slider.